# Create dynamic variables from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that contains the name of some buttons and icons for two languages.
the table is called icons and it has 4 fields (id, abbr, lang1, lang2) where abbr is the name of the variable I want to create and if the language is set to lang1 to assign the cell lang1 to the variable.

Example of the table:

```
id    abbr        lang1         lang2
-----------------------------------------------   
1     air    AirConditioner    Condizionatore
2     pool   Pool              Piscina
```

I know that I can do that with something like that

```
foreach (array('wifi','fridge','air','balcony','kitchen','tv','bathroom','pool') as $varname) {
 if ($$varname==1) 
{ 
SQL Select to get the information for each field
}
```

But I was thinking that it will be nicer if I can do that dynamically, in case I add additional rows in the table

The desired result will be to have something like this created automatically for each row

```
if ($lang==lang1)
{
$air=$row['lang1'];
$pool=$row['lang1'];
}
else
{
$air=$row['lang2'];
$pool=$row['lang2'];
}
```

I have searched if someone faced this before, but couldn't find anything usefull for my case, so any help will be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I mean right `$lang` is 1 or 2, this code may help.

```
$language = 'lang'.$lang; // creates lang1 or lang2

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM icons;");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $varname = $row['abbr'];
    $$varname = $row[$language];
}
```

Comment: The logic should be viceversa... I need the sql query to pull out the different rows and then if the language is 1 or 2 to create dynamically the variables.

Comment: it worked even the first time as I am doing GET for the $lang from the url. Than ks

Comment: Don't forget about the protection aginst sql injection, when you use a GET field!

Comment: what is your suggestion for a protection in that case... I am not very good with that

Comment: It is not essential if only you use the code, but without this protection your database is vulnerable on the internet. Included whole database. To avoid unauthorized operations, you must escaping string before the query. You can find more information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

The simplest dynamic way I can think of is that you can query the `abbr` you want, then pass the `$lang` variable as a selector to select the column of the language you want, depending on your code you can do this:

```
${$row['abbr']}=$row[$lang];
```

Comment: thats fine but how am I going to create these variables for all the records in the table? I dont want to specify abbr... I want all abbr in the database to be created dinamically.